# Find entries of 20 or more by contact within one minute of each entry

Tags: sql, sql-server

We are collecting some analytics data for contacts & each page they visit. A lot of the analytics data is from malicious attacks or bots, so they are hitting like 20+ pages of the site in under a minute. I want to be able to purge this data once a day but cant figure out how to write a SQL query that will select all rows where that contact visited more than 20 pages in a minute, not just the past minute, but throughout the day. How would I write the query to get the rows of the activities by a certain contact that had groups of 20 + activities within a minute of each other?

The analytics table has DateCreated, ContactID, ActivityName, ActivityUrl

Sample Data (lets pretend its more than 5 within a minute):

```
2020-07-25 23:59:58, 78, Page visit, /home  
2020-07-25 23:59:57, 78, Page visit, /home/1  
2020-07-25 23:59:58, 34, Page visit, /home/2  
2020-07-25 23:59:56, 78, Page visit, /home/3  
2020-07-25 23:59:55, 78, Page visit, /home/4  
2020-07-25 23:59:52, 764, Page visit, /home  
2020-07-25 23:59:52, 78, Page visit, /home/5  
2020-07-25 23:59:51, 78, Page visit, /home/6  
2020-07-25 21:34:02, 764, Page visit, /home
```

Desired data:

```
2020-07-25 23:59:58, 78, Page visit, /home  
2020-07-25 23:59:57, 78, Page visit, /home/1  
2020-07-25 23:59:56, 78, Page visit, /home/3  
2020-07-25 23:59:55, 78, Page visit, /home/4   
2020-07-25 23:59:52, 78, Page visit, /home/5  
2020-07-25 23:59:51, 78, Page visit, /home/6
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: And ask a question; you haven't asked anything here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get contacts that visited 20 pages within a minute using `lag()`:

```
select distinct contactid
from (select t.*,
             lag(datecreated, 19) over (partition by contactid order by datecreated) as lag20
      from t
     ) t
where lag20 > dateadd(minute, -1, datecreated);
```

That is, there are 20 rows within a minute if you look back 19 rows and that row is less than a minute before the current row.

Answer (score 0):

For data like:

```
n, d
John, 2020-01-01 00:00:10
John, 2020-01-01 00:00:30
John, 2020-01-01 00:00:50
John, 2020-01-01 00:01:10
John, 2020-01-01 00:01:30
John, 2020-01-01 00:01:50
```

You could group on raw minute precision of the date; it might be sufficient:

```
SELECT n, DATEDIFF(minute, CAST(d as date), d) 
FROM t
GROUP BY n, DATEDIFF(minute, CAST(d as date), d) 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 20
```

Of course, you might get someone who blats 20 requests across the minute boundary so that half fall in each minute. You could counter for that by adding 30 seconds to all their times and unioning the two queries

There are other things you could do such as a coordinated query that looks back over the past minute to find how many rows were within the same minute sliding window:

```
SELECT 
  n, 
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t tI WHERE tI.n = tO.n AND tI.d BETWEEN DATEADD(minute, -1, tO.d) AND tO.d) ct
FROM 
  t tO
```

This resultset could then be queried for a `GROUP BY n HAVING MAX(ct) > 20`..

Footnote: it's a shame SQLS doesn't support ranging on dates in its window functions like Oracle does; `COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY n ORDER BY d RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL 1 MINUTE PRECEDING AND 0)` - SQLS understands range but only for "rows preceding/following/both that have the same value as the current row" and I don't believe there's a way to adjust your continuously variable datetime so that this applies